Subspace dimension spanned by $a(1,2,\ldots,n-1)$, $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $\phi(n)/2+1$.
Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer. Consider the vector $v=(1,2,\ldots,n-1)$. For any $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, set
$$
v_a := (a \text{ mod $n$},2a \text{ mod $n$},3a \text{ mod $n$},\ldots,(n-1)a \text{ mod $n$}) \in \Bbb R^{n-1}.
$$
I want to determine the dimension of the subspace of $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ spanned by all these $v_a$.
Here are some examples:

When $n=3$, we have two vectors $v_1=(1,2)$ and $v_2=(2,1)$. They span all of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
When $n=4$, we have two vectors $v_1=(1,2,3)$ and $v_3=(3,2,1)$. They span a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
When $n=5$, we have four vectors $v_1=(1,2,3,4)$, $v_2=(2,4,1,3)$, $v_3=(3,1,4,2)$, and $v_4=(4,3,2,1)$. They span a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.
When $n=8$, we have four vectors $v_1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$, $v_3=(3,6,1,4,7,2,5)$, $v_5=(5,2,7,4,1,6,3)$, and $v_7=(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$. They span a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{7}$.

Observe that $v_a + v_{n-a}$ is always $(n,n,\ldots,n)$. Then, the subspace is at most $\phi(n)/2+1$ dimensional. I guess the dimension is exactly given by $\phi(n)/2+1$. However, I have no idea to prove the linear independency of the first $\phi(n)/2+1$ vectors. Any suggestion?

Note that $v_a = au - nw_a$ where $u=(1,2,\dots,n-1)$ and $w_a=\bigl( \lfloor \frac an \rfloor, \lfloor \frac{2a}n \rfloor, \ldots, \lfloor \frac{(n-1)a}n \rfloor \bigr)$. So it suffices (I believe) to prove that $u$ together with the first $\phi(n)/2$ of the $w_a$ are linearly independent. This might be easier since each vector's coordinates are increasing, rather than the random-seeming entries of the $v_a$.

I find that this rank is given by the sequence A326790 in OEIS. However, I cannot find any reference showing that this is $\phi(n)/2+1$.
